# Pandas Conditional Multiply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pandas newbie here (and data science newbie for that matter).

I am trying to convert current local currencies to current USD, which would involve multiplying each data point with the corresponding exchange rate. The data structure looks something like the follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.DataFrame([
            ["CNY", 321.4, 123.3, 2131, 2134],
            ["EUR", 2144, 3521, 3152, 6421],
            ["CNY", 9999, 1234, 96, 879]],
            columns=["Currency", 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003]) 
rates = pd.DataFrame([
            ["CNY", 6.1, 6.8, 7.4, 5.8],
            ["EUR", 1.1, 1.0, 2.5, 3.1]], 
            columns=["Currency", 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003])
```

I would like to multiply the annual values, i.e. data under the columns "2000," "2001," "2002", and "2003" with the respective exchange values on the condition that the currency codes match.

I have seen an [answer on a similar subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570493/multiply-two-numerical-columns-on-conditional-using-pandas) that makes use of the `where()` function. I have a feeling that that is the way to go, but in that example the person had the two dataframes in the same dimensions so it was done with a simple multiplication. My exchange rate dataframe is of a different dimension than the actual data sheet, where some currencies appear multiple times. I thought about brute forcing it by iterating through the dataset but that is just bad. I also suspect that there may be something I can do along the lines of a natural join, but unfortunately I do not know enough about data science to figure it out.

Edit: The original code was wrong in that I didn't know how to work with the constructor. I have changed the code following comments.

Comment: Your code creates empty dataframes.

Comment: Please correct your dataframes so we'll understand the structure

Comment: If you are having trouble with the DataFrame constructor: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

I have a hunch you meant:
```
dataset = pd.DataFrame([["CNY", 321.4, 123.3, 2131, 2134],["EUR", 2144, 3521, 3152, 6421],["CNY", 9999, 1234, 96, 879]],columns=["Currency", 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003])
rates = pd.DataFrame([["CNY", 6.1, 6.8, 7.4, 5.8],["EUR", 1.1, 1.0, 2.5, 3.1]], columns=["Currency", 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003])
```
Please update the original question.

Comment: Thank you @Dodd-learning. That is what I meant and I'll do the update. The actual data is read from an excel file so I didn't actually work with the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this input, use currency as index:

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.DataFrame ([
            ["CNY", 321.4, 123.3, 2131, 2134],
            ["EUR", 2144, 3521, 3152, 6421], 
            ["CNY", 9999, 1234, 96, 879]], 
            columns=["Currency", 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003])
rates = pd.DataFrame ([
            ["CNY",6.1, 6.8, 7.4, 5.8], 
            ["EUR",1.1, 1.0, 2.5, 3.1]], 
            columns=["Currency", 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003])

out = dataset.set_index('Currency').mul(rates.set_index('Currency'))
```

*Optionally `.reset_index()` to set again "Currency" as column, although it might be better to leave it as index.*

Output:

```
              2000     2001     2002     2003
Currency                                     
CNY        1960.54   838.44  15769.4  12377.2
CNY       60993.90  8391.20    710.4   5098.2
EUR        2358.40  3521.00   7880.0  19905.1
```

Or:

```
out = dataset.set_index('Currency').mul(rates.set_index('Currency').loc[dataset['Currency']])
```

Output:

```
              2000     2001     2002     2003
Currency                                     
CNY        1960.54   838.44  15769.4  12377.2
EUR        2358.40  3521.00   7880.0  19905.1
CNY       60993.90  8391.20    710.4   5098.2
```

You can also use a left merge to align the rates:

```
dataset[['Currency']].merge(rates, how='left')
```